# Passing selected object model on button press/event trigger

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I have a button that currently passes the selected value to the `removeContract()`.

```
<td class="col-md-1" colspan="1" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="removeContract(ctrl.selectValue, contractIndex)">&nbsp;<=&nbsp;</button>
</td>
<td class="col-md-5" colspan="5">
    <label class="control-label">{{item.fields[132].displayName}}</label>
    <select size="5" ng-model="ctrl.selectValue">
        <option data-ng-repeat="contract in contracts">{{contract.CONT_ORDNO}} - {{contract.SUPP_NAME}}[{{contract.SUPP_NUM}}]</option>
    </select> 
</td>
```

However, I need to send back the actual current contract model, called 'contract' above. The function's 1st parameter needs to be the currently selected contract. How would I achieve this?

Comment: if you're going to select the contract with a click, then you can add an event listener `onclick` to add an id of active to the selected contract

Comment: @RandomDeveloper data-ng-click does that job here with angular.

Comment: just pass `ctrl.selectValue` to function. do u use `controllerAs` syntax?and what is your problem exactly?

Comment: Don't understand your question clearly.. better add plunker with more explanation..

Comment: @Rohit Yes, very helpful thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Some suggestions as per the current code :**

- Instead of passing whole `{{contract.CONT_ORDNO}} - {{contract.SUPP_NAME}}[{{contract.SUPP_NUM}}]` into the ng-model just pass the `contract.CONT_ORDNO` to identify the selected data from the dropdown.

  ```
  <option data-ng-repeat="contract in contracts" value="contract.CONT_ORDNO">{{contract.CONT_ORDNO}} - {{contract.SUPP_NAME}}[{{contract.SUPP_NUM}}]</option>
  ```
- As we already have contracts array of objects inside the controller.Hence, no need to pass the second parameter inside the **`removeContract`** function.

  ```
  <button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="removeContract(ctrl.selectValue)">&nbsp;&lt;&#61;&nbsp;</button>
  ```
- Based on the selected value we can remove the `contract` object from the `contracts` array inside `removeContract` function with the help of Array [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method.

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.contracts = [
      {
        "CONT_ORDNO": "1",
        "SUPP_NAME": "alpha",
        "SUPP_NUM": "0001"
      },
      {
        "CONT_ORDNO": "2",
        "SUPP_NAME": "beta",
        "SUPP_NUM": "0002"
      },
      {
        "CONT_ORDNO": "3",
        "SUPP_NAME": "gaama",
        "SUPP_NUM": "0003"
      },
      {
        "CONT_ORDNO": "4",
        "SUPP_NAME": "xyz",
        "SUPP_NUM": "0004"
      }
    ];
    
    $scope.removeContract = function(selectedVal) {
      var removedObj = $scope.contracts.filter(function(item) {
        return item.CONT_ORDNO != selectedVal; 
      });
      console.log(removedObj);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <td class="col-md-1" colspan="1" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-ng-click="removeContract(ctrl.selectValue)">&nbsp;&lt;&#61;&nbsp;</button>
</td>
<td class="col-md-5" colspan="5">
    <label class="control-label">{{item.fields[132].displayName}}</label>
    <select size="5" ng-model="ctrl.selectValue">
        <option data-ng-repeat="contract in contracts" value="{{contract.CONT_ORDNO}}">{{contract.CONT_ORDNO}} - {{contract.SUPP_NAME}}[{{contract.SUPP_NUM}}]</option>
    </select> 
</td>   
</div>
```